# How to convert Date to "Trial Number" in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, date, numbers, data-manipulation

I have experimental data that is indexed by date but I would like to convert these dates to trial numbers instead.

Here is how my data is currently formatted

[image: Here is how my data is currently formatted]

I would like to eventually format the data to look like this:

Dose is the left-most column and the rest of the columns are the number of trials for each treatment (I already have subsets for each treatment). The data is each trial should be the data from the Response column in the first picture

[image: Dose is the left-most column and the rest of the columns are the number of trials for each treatment (I already have subsets for each treatment). The data is each trial should be the data from the Response column in the first picture]

I am pretty new to R, so any and all advice for manipulating data sets is much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Can you please use `dput` to show the data instead of images for testing. thanks

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use.Images are not helpful.  Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can work, but next time share your data using `dput()`. I have sketched a dummy data similar to that shared. Using `tidyverse` functions create a variable to track time grouping by `Dose` and then use `pivot_wider()` to arrange it as you expected. Here the code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
newdf <- yourdata %>% group_by(Dose) %>% mutate(Var=paste0('T',row_number())) %>%
  select(c(Dose,Var,Response)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Var,values_from=Response)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   Dose [7]
   Dose    T1    T2
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   0    0.05  0   
2   1    0.05  0.05
3   3    0.05  0.45
4  10    0.9  NA   
5  30   10    NA   
6   0.1  0    NA   
7   5    0.95 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create a sequence column with `rowid` from `data.table` and then pivot to 'wide' format with `pivot_wider` (from `tidyr`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>%
    mutate(Var = str_c('T', rowid(Dose)) %>%
    select(Dose, Var, Response) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = Var, values_from = Response)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
#   Dose    T1    T2
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1   0    0.05  0   
#2   1    0.05  0.05
#3   3    0.05  0.45
# ...
```